# How to concatenate 2 videos?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I have 2 videos with, probably, different resolutions, codecs, etc.

The first one is original video, second - outro.

I need them to be joined together using linux cli command(s).

I tried doing it this way:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -segment_time_metadata 1 -i test.txt -vf select=concatdec_select -af aselect=concatdec_select,aresample=async=1 out.mp4
```

But it only works correctly if i place outro in the beginning of the text file, otherwise there will be few black screen seconds instead of the outro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure **both** videos have audio:

```
ffmpeg \
-i "original video.mp4" \
-i "outro.mov" \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]scale=1280:720[scaled_v0]; \
[1:v]scale=1280:720[scaled_v1]; \
[scaled_v0][0:a][scaled_v1][1:a]\
concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac concatenated.mp4
```

If one video (e.g. the "outro.mov") has no audio stream, ffmpeg will throw the error
`Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description matches no streams.`

If you are interested in a more advanced approach that deals with audio and more, have a look at my [detailed description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216489/6444590).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate two videos of different resolution and/or codec in a way, that most players can play them, you must reencode to a common resolution and codec.

I recommend you reencode them seperately and then use the `concat` format to actually merge them, but you can also concatenate and reencode in one go. In this case you need to add codec (`-c:v` and `-c:a`) to your command line, together with the (codec-dependent) parameters as needed.